# Access Denied on vault secrets

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I am new to vault, and trying to secure data according to the k8s namespace a pod is in.  I have the authentication part sorted, but I can't make an ACL that lets a client read secrets without giving away *all* secrets

The structure i am using is `secret/k8s/<k8s-namespace>/<appname>`

e.g. `secret/k8s/bex/app1`

[image]

I have tried an ACL policy like this, but without `secret/*` I am denied access, and with `secret/*` clients can see everything, event paths adjacent to `bex`.

What am I doing wrong?

```bsh
# Without this, I cannot access anything
#path "secret/*" { capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]}

path "secret/k8s/bex*" { capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]}
path "secret/k8s/bex/*" { capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]}
path "secret/k8s/bex/app1" { capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]}
path "secret/k8s/bex/app1/*" { capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]}
path "secret/k8s/bex/app1*" { capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the vault by HarshiCorp https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s?

Comment: This is a Hashicorp Vault issue yes, but I'm not using that helm chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

This is because when you are granting *access* to secrets you need to use the `data` path after the secret backend. In your case: `secret/data/k8s/bex/app1`

Long version:

If you are using the older (deprecated) KV1 version then your policy looks like this:

```
path "secret/dev/team-1/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update", "read"]
}
```

If (I assume) you are using the new KV2 secret engine (default), then the reading versions are prefixed with the `data/` path.

```
path "secret/data/dev/team-1/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update", "read"]
}
```

More in the [Official Docs](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2#acl-rules).

Comment: Thanks - it was that pesky `data` prefix